# Add a field to Page Admin to include icon for menu item

Tags: django, django-cms

I have allowed for, in my html template, using icons with either small square png's or  with font-awesome:

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search</a> // using font-awesome
// or
<a href="#"><img src="images/icons/search.png">Search</a> // using images
```

In the template top-menu.html, I need to be able to use the following:

```
{{ child.menu_icon_font_awesome }} # in place of "icon-search"
{{ child.menu_icon_image }} # in place of "images/icons/search.png"
```

How does one get these variables into the child menu nodes in the menu?

Also, how do I get the fieldsets to work in admin.py (much less important)?

My menu_icons app looks like this:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
  """
    Deletes file of same name if exists.
  """
  def _save(self, name, content):
    if self.exists(name):
      self.delete(name)
    return super(OverwriteStorage, self)._save(name, content)

  def get_available_name(self, name):
    return name

class MenuIconFontAwesome(models.Model):
  """
    Defines Font Awesome Menu Icon
  """
  page = models.ForeignKey(Page,
                           unique=True,
                           verbose_name=_("Page"),
                           editable=False)
  menu_icon_font_awesome = models.CharField(max_length=48,
                                            verbose_name="Font Awesome Menu Icon",
                                            blank=True)

class MenuIconImage(models.Model):
  """
    Defines Image Menu Icon
  """
  page = models.ForeignKey(Page,
                           unique=True,
                           verbose_name=_("Page"),
                           editable=False)
  menu_icon_image = models.ImageField('Menu Icon Image',
                                      upload_to = 'menu_icons/',
                                      blank=True,null=True)


# admin.py
from models import MenuIconFontAwesome, MenuIconImage
from cms.admin.pageadmin import PageAdmin
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
from django.contrib import admin

class MenuIconFontAwesomeAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  """
    Adds field for Font Awesome Menu Icon
  """
  model = MenuIconFontAwesome
  fieldsets = (
    ('Menu Icon with Font Awesome', {
      'fields': ('menu_icon_font_awesome',),
    }),
  )

class MenuIconImageAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  """
    Adds field for Image Menu Icon
  """
  model = MenuIconImage
  fieldsets = (
    ('Menu Icon with Uploaded Image', {
      'fields': ('menu_icon_image',),
    }),
  )

PageAdmin.inlines.append(MenuIconFontAwesomeAdmin)
PageAdmin.inlines.append(MenuIconImageAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(Page)
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)


# views.py
# this is the part I cannot figure out
```

Here is the additions using the tip for navigation modifiers. It gives the error, "type object 'MenuIconFontAwesome' has no attribute 'menu_icon_font_awesome'" I am sure there is something obvious I am missing.

```
from menus.base import Modifier
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
from models import MenuIconFontAwesome, MenuIconImage

class MenuIconsMod(Modifier):
    """
    Add Menu Icons to the menu nodes
    """

    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        if post_cut:
            return nodes
        for node in nodes:
            node.menu_icon_font_awesome = MenuIconFontAwesome.menu_icon_font_awesome
            node.menu_icon_image = MenuIconImage.menu_icon_image
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_modifier(MenuIconsMod)
```

Regarding the fieldsets; what I am seeing looks like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LQZM.jpg. I just can't sort why those fieldsets get those names and how to override them.

Comment: This has been up for a while, and in that time I have made a lot of progress. I am most stuck on this last part and would appreciate any help. I have updated all the code to what I am doing currently. I have not found documentation that I understand which tells me how to add attributes to a menu node. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at menu modifiers (https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.5/extending_cms/app_integration.html#navigation-modifiers), using NavigationNode.attr property you should be able to add any customized data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I think that is the ticket. I have tried several different methods to get this to work. This is the one that seemed most logical, although I cannot get anything to work. I can't figure out how to call the variables from the model, and I can't figure out how to tie each one to the specific node. Please take a look at the addition above and let me know what you think.

Comment: What's the nodes supposed to be? CMS pages or else? In the node object you have a few data (in the `attr` attribute of each node) which you can use get the correct `MenuIconImage`/`MenuIconFontAwesome`. AFAIK they are not really documented, but you should easily get them from the code.

Comment: Well if I hardcode a string like "icon-search" into node.menu_icon_font_awesome = "icon-search" I can use {{ child.menu_icon_font_awesome }} in the template. What I cannot figure out is how to get the actual variable into the menu.py from each page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment, so I will try to wrap it up here.

Can you post some code of what "you have allowed for" in the template? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

If you want to upload an image trough django admin, you need to have an `menu_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = '/images/')` in your class in your models.py file, and than include it in the template by saying `<img src="{{ object.menu_image.url }}" alt="menu_image_description" />`. 
And than in the admin.py write

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.models import *

class MYModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name',)


admin.site.register(MuModelName, MyModelNameAdmin)
```

What is with the font? Can you edit your question and include the template, the admin.py and the models.py you have till now?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I was not clear enough and have edited to give further detail.

Comment: ok, so, you can have a field as I suggested where you upload an image, but make it `menu_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = '/images/', blank=True, null=True)` and in the template where you have `{{ child.get_menu_icon }}` do `{% if menu_image %}<img src="{{ menu_image.url"> />{% else %}<i class="icon-search"></i>{% endif %}` so if you have uploaded an image it will be placed, if not, the other code will be enabled in the template.

Comment: tell me if this makes sense to you, or I am still not getting your point :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. It is starting to make sense, but there is a bit on confusion. I just want it to be a text field where I enter the html because "icon-search" is not static. Basically I need to be able to use either type of icon. You have tipped me off that it would be a good idea to allow the image upload or declare the icon class and have a radio to select which. Wow, am I out of my league here. I will report back how far I get.